# Why are these sql statements deadlocking?(graph included)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-deadlocks

I'm quite surprised to see that a very basic update statement & select statement can turn into a deadlock.
I was under the impression that you could only get a deadlock if the 2 processes would be waiting on each other for infinity. What i don't get is why these 2 processes can't just wait for each other. Any help would be appreciated.

1 query comes from entity framework and is running quite aggresively(about once every 2 seconds).

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[SubscriptionID] AS [SubscriptionID], 
[Extent1].[ClientID] AS [ClientID], 
[Extent1].[SubClientID] AS [SubClientID], 
[Extent1].[CAClientID] AS [CAClientID], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ArrivalTime] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ArrivalTime] END AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate]
FROM [dbo].[CA_Event_Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] &gt; @p__linq__0)
```

The other one is doing an update :

```
UPDATE
CA_Event_Person
SET
UpdatePersonID = @PersonID,
UpdateDate = GETDATE(),
AutoAssign = ISNULL(@AutoAssign, AutoAssign)
WHERE SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID
```

Full deadlock graph:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="processc35888508">
  <process-list>
   <process id="processc35888508" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 9:72057707739217920 (fa9c88953e05)" waittime="3892" ownerId="39577235946" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.027" XDES="0x80099800" lockMode="S" schedulerid="15" kpid="9996" status="suspended" spid="109" sbid="0" ecid="5" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.027" lastbatchcompleted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.027" clientapp="iXtranet.NET2" hostname="HB2949" hostpid="4244" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="39577235946" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="102" sqlhandle="0x02000000263a730faf73af4e669327dd034762624d86b5aa">
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[SubscriptionID] AS [SubscriptionID], 
    [Extent1].[ClientID] AS [ClientID], 
    [Extent1].[SubClientID] AS [SubClientID], 
    [Extent1].[CAClientID] AS [CAClientID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ArrivalTime] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ArrivalTime] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate]
    FROM [dbo].[CA_Event_Person] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] &gt; @p__linq__0)     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="processf1137fdc8" taskpriority="0" logused="296" waitresource="PAGE: 9:1:11298302" waittime="4074" ownerId="39577243359" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.217" XDES="0x1c47b7280" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="12" kpid="10040" status="suspended" spid="237" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.217" lastbatchcompleted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.213" clientapp="Internet Information Services" hostname="HB2949" hostpid="4244" loginname="WEBCLASSIC2" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="39577243359" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="dixyscom.dbo.CA_stp_Subscription_Resource_Append" line="131" stmtstart="7222" sqlhandle="0x03000900ab5fd53ec3e5e3005aa500000100000000000000">
UPDATE
    CA_Event_Person
SET
    UpdatePersonID = @PersonID,
    UpdateDate = GETDATE(),
    AutoAssign = ISNULL(@AutoAssign, AutoAssign)
WHERE
    SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 1054171051]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process10ad13e748" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="3892" schedulerid="22" kpid="5452" status="suspended" spid="109" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.027" lastbatchcompleted="2016-03-02T13:36:42.027" clientapp="iXtranet.NET2" hostname="HB2949" hostpid="4244" loginname="WEBDOTNET3" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="39577235946" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="102" sqlhandle="0x02000000263a730faf73af4e669327dd034762624d86b5aa">
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[SubscriptionID] AS [SubscriptionID], 
    [Extent1].[ClientID] AS [ClientID], 
    [Extent1].[SubClientID] AS [SubClientID], 
    [Extent1].[CAClientID] AS [CAClientID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ArrivalTime] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ArrivalTime] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate]
    FROM [dbo].[CA_Event_Person] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] &gt; @p__linq__0)     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7))SELECT 
    [Extent1].[SubscriptionID] AS [SubscriptionID], 
    [Extent1].[ClientID] AS [ClientID], 
    [Extent1].[SubClientID] AS [SubClientID], 
    [Extent1].[CAClientID] AS [CAClientID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ArrivalTime] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent1].[ArrivalTime] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate]
    FROM [dbo].[CA_Event_Person] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[UpdateDate] &gt; @p__linq__0)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057707739217920" dbid="9" objectname="dixyscom.dbo.CA_Event_Person" indexname="CIX_CA_Event_Person" id="lock2dda41680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057707739217920">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processf1137fdc8" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processc35888508" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="11298302" dbid="9" objectname="dixyscom.dbo.CA_Event_Person" id="lock44facf180" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057707632197632">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process10ad13e748" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processf1137fdc8" mode="IX" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <exchangeEvent id="Pipecd899e380" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="1">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processc35888508"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process10ad13e748"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </exchangeEvent>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

*Edit*
There are some triggers on the table, in short these are the update triggers :
number1:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT EventID FROM deleted WHERE SubscriptionID = 7379958 and PersonID > 0) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT EventID FROM INSERTED WHERE SubscriptionID = 7379958 and PersonID = 0) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Can''t reset to PersonID 0',16,1)
    ROLLBACK

END
```

number 2:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT EventID FROM DELETED WHERE EventID > 0) OR EXISTS (SELECT EventID FROM INSERTED WHERE EventID > 0) BEGIN ... 
[Enter 30 lines of code that i'm assuming are being skipped due to the no insert or delete)
```

and number 3(which is an after update trigger):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_CA_Event_Person_RN_Availability_Recalculate_OnUpdate]
   ON [dbo].[CA_Event_Person]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF Update(EventID) OR Update(NOPersons) OR Update(StatusID) OR Update(Deleted) OR Update(Cancelled) OR Update(WaitinglistPosition) OR Update(CanBeOverTaken) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO
        RN_Availability_Recalculate
        (
            ClientID,
            SubClientID,
            ApplicationID,
            CA_CAClientID,
            CA_EventID,
            InsertPersonID,
            InsertDate,
            CompanyID,
            Reference
        )   
    SELECT
        CA_Event_Head.ClientID,
        CA_Event_Head.SubClientID,
        CA_Event_Head.ApplicationID,
        CA_Event_Head.CAClientID,
        CA_Event_Head.EventID,
        INSERTED.InsertPersonID,
        GETDATE(),
        Company.CompanyID,
        'trig_CA_Event_Person_RN_OnUpdate'
    FROM
        INSERTED
        INNER JOIN deleted
            ON deleted.SubscriptionID = INSERTED.SubscriptionID
            AND (
                deleted.EventID <> INSERTED.EventID
                OR deleted.NOPersons <> INSERTED.NOPersons
                OR deleted.ArrivalTime <> INSERTED.ArrivalTime
                OR (
                    deleted.StatusID <> INSERTED.StatusID
                    AND INSERTED.StatusID IN (50, 98, 99) --vertrokken of geannuleerd
                    )
            )
        INNER JOIN CA_Event_Head WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON INSERTED.EventID = CA_Event_Head.EventID 
        INNER JOIN Company WITH(NOLOCK) 
            ON CA_Event_Head.ClientID = Company.REF_ClientID
            AND CA_Event_Head.CAClientID = Company.REF_CA_CAClientID
            AND CA_Event_Head.ApplicationID = Company.REF_ApplicationID
    WHERE
        INSERTED.EventID > 0
        AND INSERTED.EventID NOT IN (SELECT CA_EventID FROM RN_Availability_Recalculate WITH (NOLOCK))
        AND CA_Event_Head.CAClientID > 0
        AND CA_Event_Head.PublicSubscription = 1
        AND CA_Event_Head.BlockPublicSubscription = 0
        AND CA_Event_Head.EndTime >= GETDATE()

    END
```

Comment: As for why I'm not sure, but have you tried running the EF query from a transaction with `IsolationLevel=ReadUncommitted`? This might a) give you a workaround or b) help you debugging.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your table? Are you starting any transactions from within your application?

Comment: So far i'm only seeing the deadlocks on a hot production environment. I'm skeptical about just trying stuff out without really knowing what is happening.

Comment: both queries are running inside same transaction? The select query is under transaction?

Comment: @TomH No transactions are started from within the application. I just checked and it does appear that there are a few(too many ... sigh) triggers on it. Obviously triggers are bad but could they be involved in the deadlocking?

Comment: Yes, the triggers could very easily be responsible for the deadlocks. It depends on what they're doing though.

Comment: I've looked through the triggers and none of them seem to be the culprit(i was hoping/expecting to find something that did another select on my initial table, which would've explained it) I added the triggers to the question